# MySQL - populating a column with a substring from another column in the same row

Tags: mysql

I would like to run over an entire table, populating the value of a newly created column with a substring of a value from another column.

Given a table structure not unlike the following:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email  | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Which contains data resembling:

```
+----+-------------------------+--------+
| id | email                   | domain |
+----+-------------------------+--------+
|  1 | bob@domain1.com         | NULL   |
|  2 | jim@domain1.com         | NULL   |
|  3 | terry@domain1.com       | NULL   |
|  4 | frank@anotherdomain.com | NULL   |
|  5 | linda@anotherdomain.com | NULL   |
|  6 | craig@thethird.com      | NULL   |
+----+-------------------------+--------+
```

I would like to have a query to parse the domain portion of the email address, and put it in the domain column, to end up with a result like:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
| id | email                   | domain            |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | bob@domain1.com         | domain1.com       |
|  2 | jim@domain1.com         | domain1.com       |
|  3 | terry@domain1.com       | domain1.com       |
|  4 | frank@anotherdomain.com | anotherdomain.com |
|  5 | linda@anotherdomain.com | anotherdomain.com |
|  6 | craig@thethird.com      | thethird.com      |
+----+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Currently, I am doing this *outside* of the MySQL engine with a shell script, but this is inefficient, and I'm sure there must be a better way to do it inside of the MySQL engine.

Efficiency is important here, as the tables I will be doing this on in production are tens or even hundreds of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT
  id,
  email,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1) domain
FROM
  yourtable
```

or this to update your data:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0865/1).

Comment: You're not updating the table like all the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
update your_table
set domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)
where domain is null;
```

If the table is large you should consider splitting the update into chunks. I recommend using the [`split`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_split.html) function in common_schema to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

> If count is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter
>   (counting from the right) is returned.

So to get everything to the right of the `@`, you can provide a negative count:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f04fd/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
-1 will give the value after `@`

update tablename set domain = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)
```