# update specific column of mysql table

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update, trim

I have a quite big table in mysql and I need to change all the records related to this column.

records are like this :

```
/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1, 
/name/nm0000151/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t2, 
...,  
/name/nm0104594/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10
```

what I want is to keep only the string in the middle which is `nm0000209`, `nm0000151`,.... I know how to delete specific characters from the right or left of the words by `REPLACE` or Trim , .., but my problem is that in this case the number of characters in the third part of string are not equal (as you see when it reaches to 10, I have to delete 21 characters from the end instead of 20 characters and since this table contains lots of records I dont know how to do it.

I reaaly appreciate if someone could helop me,

thanks

Comment: Have you tried the Update statment? UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

Comment: So, your current table has ```/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1``` in the target field, and you need to clean it up and leave only the nm00000209 part? Because I'm confused if that strings you quoted are already in the database or are requests you have yet to parse

Comment: This might help: "populating a column with a substring" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644317/mysql-populating-a-column-with-a-substring-from-another-column-in-the-same-row

Comment: @amenadiel yes, exactly! I have /name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1 in my table and I need only nm0000209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want is to keep only the string in the middle which is nm0000209, nm0000151...*

You can use `'SUBSTRING_INDEX'` on the column to crop part of the column value.

Following example assumes that the said column will have `'name/'` as starting pattern.

**Example**:

```
update table_name
 set column_name = substring_index( 
                       substring_index( column_name, 'name/', -1 )
                     , '/', 1 );
```

The same can be used for updating with the same value.

***Demo*** @ [***MySQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2ab8e/1)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use MYSQL's SUBSTRING_INDEX function. It would let you get whatever's after the last slash. Or after the second to last.

[image]

For your particular case

```
select 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(thefield,'/',-2 ),'/', 1) 
from supertext
```

would yield the desired result

EDIT: for update purposes

```
 UPDATE thetable 
 SET thefield=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(thefield,'/',-2 ),'/', 1)
```

Comment: see my edit. @Ravinder's good too if all your strings start with 'name'